# Spring boot - integration testing - WebTestClient & HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testng, integration-testing, spring-webflux

I'm having difficulties figuring this out.

I can mock almost everything but for some reason the `HttpServletRequest` is mocked but not injected into the `@ControllerAdvice` `@ExceptionHandler` method.

Any ideas? Thank you for your help in advance!

**STR** Repo with minimal plug and play test suite / code

https://github.com/krodyrobi/spring-integration-test-str

```
@Component
public class Config {
  private final String url = "https://httpstat.us/";

  public String getUrl() {
    return url;
  }
}

@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(WebClientResponseException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(HttpServletRequest request, WebClientResponseException ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(request.getRequestURL() + " " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), ex.getStatusCode());
    }
}



@RestController
public class SomeController {
  private final Config config;

  @Autowired
  public SomeController(Config config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  @GetMapping("/test")
  public Mono<String> test() {
     return WebClient
       .create(config.getUrl())
       .get()
       .uri("/200")
       .retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(String.class);
  }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
  SomeController.class,
  GlobalExceptionHandler.class,
})
public class SomeControllerTest {
  private final static String baseUrl = "http://localhost:9999/";

  public @Rule WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(9999);

  private @MockBean Config config;
  private @MockBean HttpServletRequest request;

  private WebTestClient webClient;

  private @Autowired SomeController controller;
  private @Autowired GlobalExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    webClient = WebTestClient
      .bindToController(controller)
      .controllerAdvice(exceptionHandler)
      .build();

    when(config.getUrl()).thenReturn(baseUrl);
  }

  @Test
  public void test_works() {
    wireMockRule
      .stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/200"))
      .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                    .withBody("200 MOCK")));

    webClient
      .get()
      .uri("/test")
      .exchange()
      .expectStatus()
      .isOk()
      .expectBody(String.class)
      .isEqualTo("200 MOCK");

    wireMockRule.verify(getRequestedFor(urlMatching("/200")));
  }

  @Test
  public void test_fails() {
    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument 0 
    // of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' on public 
    // org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> 
    // com.example.demo.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleException(
    //   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
    //   ...client.WebClientResponseException
    // )

    wireMockRule
      .stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/200"))
      .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(404)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                    .withBody("404 MOCK")));

    webClient
       .get()
       .uri("/test")
       .exchange()
       .expectStatus()
       .isNotFound()
       .expectBody(String.class)
       .isEqualTo("Http://localhost:8080/test 404 MOCK");

    wireMockRule.verify(getRequestedFor(urlMatching("/200")));
  }
}
```

Comment: After going through the code on GitHub, I was wondering why is `HttpServletRequest` mocked?

Comment: Mocked or not the same error is occurring, I don't have an explicit reason to mock it as I'd expect the `WebTestClient` to populate it with data for its request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below instead of `HttpServletRequest`

```
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;

ServerHttpRequest request
```

Comment: Apparently this only works when testing... Not when running a real request which is weird.